# How to use two commands in python -c?

Tags: python

I am wanting to execute python command by using python -c but it contain in string library so i need import it.
While reading man i find this:

```
when called with -c  command,  it  executes  the
   Python  statement(s) given as command.  Here command may contain multi‐
   ple statements separated by newlines.  Leading whitespace  is  signifi‐
   cant  in  Python statements!  In non-interactive mode, the entire input
   is parsed before it is executed.
```

For example I've tried python3 -c "import string \n print(string.ascii_letters)"
but it didn't work. So what is it new line?

Comment: how is this RE related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a re related question. But you can do something like this:

```
python3 -c 'import string;print(string.ascii_letters)'
```

Comment: Thank you so much